# SBT adding an extra tag to dependency location

Tags: mongodb, maven, playframework, sbt, mongodb-java

I'm very new to the *SBT / Maven* build process and have been struggling to add the *Java MongoDB Async Driver* to my Play framework application. I've looked everywhere for a solution since this seems like a simple issue but haven't been able to find anything since I don't really know what to look for.

In my build.sbt file:

`addSbtPlugin("org.mongodb" % "mongodb-driver-async" % "3.2.1")`

Compiling the code:

`[info] Resolving org.mongodb#mongodb-driver-async;3.2.1 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.mongodb#mongodb-driver-async;3.2.1
...
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-async_2.10_0.13/3.2.1/mongodb-driver-async-3.2.1.pom`

The correct address is:

`https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-async/3.2.1/mongodb-driver-async-3.2.1.pom`

Is there any way to 'remove' the extra `_2.10_0.13` so that the project is able to find the pom file? Or is there an easier solution I have overlooked?

Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As its just a normal dependency rather than an sbt plugin, you should use

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb" % "mongodb-driver-async" % "3.2.1"
```

in your build.sbt file

[docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Dependencies.html#The++key) here